Expression returns '#Error' in SSRS 2019, expression was working until some time ago
This expression was working until some time ago, and now it is returning #error in the cell:
=Format(First(Fields!dateEnd.Value, "myDs"), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")

What I have already tried:
=first(Fields!dateEnd.Value, "myDs")

returned the value correctly
=Format(Now, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")

returned the date formatted as expected.
It seems that when using the functions together, it returns this #Error.
Additionally, if I try to use a string in the expression, it also gives #Error, like this:
"The current time: " + Format(Now, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")


Concatenation in SSRS Expressions is done with & not +
Is the dateEnd value ever null? Or perhaps the type of the column not date/datetime? that may explain the #Error returned by passing it to the Format function.
I generally prefer to format date fields in placeholders instead of within the expression itself

What is the full error?

It it just a typo that there is no = before "The current time: " + Format(Now, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm") expression? This works fine for me BTW

The error was on the SSRS server, as I had described; it was working and then just stopped. On the server, they deleted the necessary SDK for SSRS to function, and it was returning the 'Error' because the kit was required to execute the native functions.
